# Weblogic fmw_infrastructure 12c Docker Container- Domain Creation Failed.. Please check the Domain Logs

Tags: oracle, docker, weblogic12c, docker-image, container-image

I am trying to run a weblogic 12.2.1.2 docker image but I am getting stuck at the Domain creation phase..

I followed the instructions in container-registry.oracle.com and yet had to make some changes to get it till the Domain creation phase which gives me the following log..

```
Error: set() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.
Error: runCmd() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/u01/oracle/container-scripts/createInfraDomain.py", line 265, in ?
  File "/u01/oracle/container-scripts/createInfraDomain.py", line 53, in createInfraDomain
  File "/u01/oracle/container-scripts/createInfraDomain.py", line 66, in createBaseDomain
  File "/tmp/WLSTOfflineIni2843296184802971251.py", line 79, in set
  File "/tmp/WLSTOfflineIni2843296184802971251.py", line 19, in command
    at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.CommandExceptionHandler.handleException(CommandExceptionHandler.java:69)
    at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.handleException(WLScriptContext.java:2768)
    at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.runCmd(WLScriptContext.java:701)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException

RetVal from Domain creation 1
Domain Creation Failed.. Please check the Domain Logs
```

I tried to locate the domain logs but failed..

please help me resolve this issue!

Thanks a lot !!

this is what I see:

```
 docker run -p 9001:7001 --network=InfraNET -v $HOST_VOLUME:/u01/oracle/user_projects --name InfraAdminContainer --env-file ./infraDomain.env.list container-registry.oracle.com/middleware/fmw-infrastructure:12.2.1.2
Configuring Domain for first time run
=====================================
Password does not Match the criteria, re-generating...

    Database Schema password Auto Generated :

    ----> Database schema password: z8zAJQY1

CONNECTION_STRING=InfraDB:1521/InfraPDB1.us.oracle.com
RCUPREFIX=INFRA6
DOMAIN_NAME=InfraDomain
Loading RCU Phase
=================
CONNECTION_STRING=InfraDB:1521/InfraPDB1.us.oracle.com
RCUPREFIX=INFRA6
DB_PASSWORD=Oradoc_db1
jdbc_url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@InfraDB:1521/InfraPDB1.us.oracle.com
ADMIN_PASSWORD=MyWLSAdminPassword
DB_SCHEMA_PASSWORD=z8zAJQY1
DB_USERNAME=sys
DOMAIN_HOME: /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/InfraDomain
Loading SOA RCU into database
MW_HOME: /u01/oracle
WL_HOME: /u01/oracle/wlserver
ADMIN_USER: weblogic
DOMAIN_ROOT: /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains
DOMAIN HOME: /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/InfraDomain
Domain Configuration Phase
==========================

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

/u01/oracle/container-scripts/createInfraDomain.py called with the following sys.argv array:
sys.argv[0] = /u01/oracle/container-scripts/createInfraDomain.py
sys.argv[1] = -oh
sys.argv[2] = /u01/oracle
sys.argv[3] = -jh
sys.argv[4] = /usr/java/default
sys.argv[5] = -parent
sys.argv[6] = /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains
sys.argv[7] = -name
sys.argv[8] = InfraDomain
sys.argv[9] = -user
sys.argv[10] = weblogic
sys.argv[11] = -password
sys.argv[12] = MyWLSAdminPassword
sys.argv[13] = -rcuDb
sys.argv[14] = InfraDB:1521/InfraPDB1.us.oracle.com
sys.argv[15] = -rcuPrefix
sys.argv[16] = INFRA6
sys.argv[17] = -rcuSchemaPwd
sys.argv[18] = z8zAJQY1
Error: set() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.
Error: runCmd() failed. Do dumpStack() to see details.
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/u01/oracle/container-scripts/createInfraDomain.py", line 265, in ?
  File "/u01/oracle/container-scripts/createInfraDomain.py", line 53, in createInfraDomain
  File "/u01/oracle/container-scripts/createInfraDomain.py", line 66, in createBaseDomain
  File "/tmp/WLSTOfflineIni2843296184802971251.py", line 79, in set
  File "/tmp/WLSTOfflineIni2843296184802971251.py", line 19, in command
    at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.CommandExceptionHandler.handleException(CommandExceptionHandler.java:69)
    at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.handleException(WLScriptContext.java:2768)
    at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.runCmd(WLScriptContext.java:701)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException: com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLSTException

RetVal from Domain creation 1
Domain Creation Failed.. Please check the Domain Logs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the RCU.out file and figired out that i was using an existing RCU-prefix..
Gave a new prefix and it worked.